# Does it make sense to keep class 1 airports open with few airplanes?

Tags: pocket-planes

I'm about level 17 or so on Pocket Planes, and I have been mostly opening class 2 and 3 airports now that I can afford to. I'm noticing that I have a ton of jobs now that I can't fulfill; I only have 11 airplanes. Does it make sense to keep class 1 airports open, if they're just going to generate jobs I can't fulfill? I can make more money with larger airplanes going to/from the larger airports anyway.

Of course, some of them would remain open as waypoints between cities so that the smaller planes can still fly from city to city.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not make sense to keep those class 1 airports open.  The jobs that are allocated are distributed across all the airports you have, so by closing the class 1 airports more of your jobs will be to class 2 and 3 destinations that are easier to combine and make use of your current fleet.

Keeping a couple of class 1 airports open as waypoints is reasonable, but for more efficiently generating income it's best to just have class 3 airports, upgraded to have the most layovers (and jobs) appearing and have them spaced at the range of your class 3 aircraft.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to hit level 22 in about 5,000XP and honestly I think I'm going to keep my class 1s. So far I've bought everything north of Kansas City along with a bridge to Europe with two class 1s there. I basically have a "highway" of planes going from Bergen (Sweden) to the Alaskan cities like Nome, Barrow, and a bunch more up in that corner. I tend to earn about 2,000 per flight and have no use buying class 2 planes just because all the cities up there are class 1.

Buying and selling class 1 airports depends entirely on where you are and what planes are your big money earners. If you're in Europe or east Asia, you probably operate out of mostly class 2 anyway and you might as well sell class 1s. But if you're in southeast Asia or Africa or somewhere its mostly class 1, just buy as many kangaroos as you can. But if it is overwhelmed with class 2/3s I would suggest making the switch.